# Agrupar en una sola fila

Tags: sql-server

Buen día, tengo una tabla donde se repiten registros, cada registro tiene un identificador unico en mi caso es el nombre de la persona. Ademas hay 3 columnas que presentan o no presentan datos. Lo que deseo es poder agrupar en una sola fila.

```html
SELECT [NOMBRES]
      ,[Dosis1_FechaVacunacion]
      ,[Dosis2_FechaVacunacion]
      ,[Dosis3_FechaVacunacion]
  FROM [Pruebas].[dbo].[VPHMILAGROS]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tengo una tabla donde se repiten registros, cada registro tiene un identificador unico . Seguro¿?¿? Si tienen identificador único, como es posible que se repitan??

Comment: error mio, me refería al nombre

Comment: El nombre es el identificador unico?? o a parte del nombre tienen un ID. Porque si te aparece 2 veces el mismo nombre. Nombre no es el identificador de la tabla

Comment: no existe identificador único, fue un error mio.

Comment: Si te fijas, todo nombre tiene 3 ocurrencias. Una por cada fecha de vacunacion. Es decir sin que nombre fuese un ID unico. Hiciste tres insert diferentes. Cuando debiste hacer solo uno, con todos los datos. O un insert y uno o dos updates

Comment: El problema aqui es que ya tienes datos, repetidos, por lo que cambiar la tabla para que el nombre sea el ID, te dara un error. Lo mejor, salvar los datos. Borrar o vaciar la tabla y por ultimo crear o modificar la tabla y añadir los datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola Fernando Salidas:

Por lo que veo en la imagen, parece que puedes aplicar un max y agrupar.

```
SELECT [NOMBRES]
  ,Max([Dosis1_FechaVacunacion])
  ,Max([Dosis2_FechaVacunacion])
  ,Max([Dosis3_FechaVacunacion])
FROM [Pruebas].[dbo].[VPHMILAGROS]
group by [Nombres]
```

Comment: Eso no soluciona nada. Solo presenta los datos de otra forma

Comment: Su problema esta en el diseño de la tabla , donde , como al contrario que el dice . No tiene un identificador unico. Por eso se le repiten lineas

Comment: muchas gracias @javi-fer2 solucionó mi problema

Comment: De nada Fernando Salinas. A lo mejor te interesa echarle un ojo a este artículo, que escribí hace un poco sobre group by. https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/group-by-quizas-la-clausula-mas-conflictiva/